# SSRS 2008 R2 Subscriptions Tab Missing From Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Some reports in my company have a **My Suscriptions** tab to it, and a **New Subscription** button too:

[image]

I'm working off a different SQL Server 2008 R2 with Reporting Services. I have Visual Studio 2008 on my PC. The reports I wrote don't have any of that, or any other "user-friendly" way to subscribe to reports.

According to [this Sep 2010 post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/52aab8fb-9f57-45df-9ae7-c3d8dd218a22/) that's the way it is.

Is there any more current information on that? Or any other way out?

Thanks!

Added: But according to [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157386%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) on 2008 R2 it seems to imply that there should be a Subscriptions tab...

This is what I have of SQL server on my PC:

[image: SQL Server Installed SW on my PC]

Comment: if you are using SQL SERVER Express on your PC? if yes then SQL Agent is not installed due to that suncription tab does not exist!

Comment: As far as I know I don't. But I'm posting a screenshot on the opening post.

Comment: I really don't understand why this was closed as "off topic" as it clearly fulfills both the "software tools commonly used by programmers" and "practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face" criteria. Don't let this put you off asking questions in future!

Comment: @Nathan - thanks for your support. What do I do about this?

Comment: Unfortunately there doesn't appear to be any way to appeal this process apart from creating an entry in the Stackoverflow "Meta" forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MSDN article refers to opening a report and clicking on a Subscriptions tab for SQL Server 2008 R2 - this is incorrect.

In 2008 R2, to subscribe to a report you first locate the report in Report Manager, then *hover* the cursor over the report link. This highlights a drop-down arrow, click on this and select "Subscribe" from the menu.

[image: Report Manager Subscribe link]

Alternatively, if you have permissions to "Manage" reports, then you can click on Manage and then there is a "Subscriptions" tab listed on the left.

[image: Subscriptions tab]

"My subscriptions" should be accessible from a link at the top-right of the Report Manager screen.

Comment: Thanks Nathan. That's precisely the "problem" that the first link in my post refers to. I guess that the person posting - as well as myself - doesn't want to have the users go through that will all that options. So you are saying basically that the MSDN article is wrong, and that the forum post is right. Correct?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the MSDN article is wrong where it says: "In Report Manager, on the Contents page, navigate to the report you want to subscribe to. Click the report to open it. Click the Subscriptions tab, and then click New Subscription." Once a report has been opened in 2008 R2 Report Manager there is no "Subscriptions tab" or any way to create a subscription. This can be done at the folder level by accessing the report drop down menu as I described.

Comment: What I did is to add a link to Subscribe in the rendered report. Thanks.